# script shell mv with wildcard does not work

Tags: shell

I am trying to copy all files in a directory starting with a certain prefix using wildcard. Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash 

path="/home/scoubidou/recovered/"
prefix="f"

for i in "$@"
do
    if [ ! -d "$path$prefix$i" ]; then
        mkdir $path$prefix$i
    fi
    echo $path$prefix$i* $path$prefix$i
    mv $path$prefix$i* $path$prefix$i
done
```

However, this is not working. The wildcard seems not to be working and the expression is taken with a string. Note that the command works just fine in the terminal.

Comment: Not sure I am following, what exactly are you passing to the script? (side note: you can just use "for i" as bash will then assume 'in "$@"')

Comment: Its a number (e.g. 70). It looks like the wildcard does not work.

Comment: So now I am more confused?? You are passing a single value to the script, so why would you need a loop at all? You then check if path/f70 exists to then move the directory into itself??? or are there files or directories with names starting with f70 that need to be moved?  Maybe it would help if you provided some data of what is actually in the directory you are working in?

Comment: Hi grail. Exactly, I have files starting with f70 inside /home/scoubidou/recovered, that I want to move to /home/scoubidou/recovered/f70 directory. I know that it is not really optimized as it will try to move f70 to itself which raises an error. But the above commands work just fine in a terminal.

Comment: Try using - set -xv - at the start of your script and it will output what is happening.  This will indicate variable values and glob expansions

Comment: Thank you all. Using shopt -s extglob in the beginning of the script seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
`mv $path$prefix$i* $path$prefix$i`
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately, this seems to take the complete command as a string.